# How to use jquery to find xml element with ':' in name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to use jquery to parse and find an xml element.  The element I'm trying to find has an odd name "ex:relatedid" and for some reason jquery seems to not be able to find it.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

XML

```
    <item>
        <id>3ac0daff-51c7-40f2-9396-e0c6adf50858</id>
        <published>2014-12-09T11:27:43.000Z</published>
        <updated>2014-12-09T11:27:43.000Z</updated>
        <ex:relatedid>7fa16377-3382-4ad9-ac52-7ee139e7d9ce</relatedid>
```

jquery that doesn't work

```
 $(xml).find('item').each(function () {

          //works
          var id = $(this).find('id').text();

          //doesn't work
          var ex = $(this).find('ex:relatedid').text();

          console.log(ex);

   });
```

Comment: escaping `$(this).find('ex\\:relatedid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this it will work, you need to escape "characters" like ":"

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utzaa8q7/)

```
$('xml').find('item').each(function () {

      //works
      var id = $(this).find('id').text();

      //doesn't work
      var ex = $(this).find('ex\\:relatedid').text();

      console.log(ex);
```

});